# Can't find absolute positioning rules in CSS specification

Tags: css, language-lawyer, w3c

According to Mozilla Developer Network's [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) on CSS `position` property, setting `position` as `absolute` has the following behavior:

> **absolute**
>
> > Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest ***positioned*** ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins.

However, in the official [CSS specification as of 2015](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) I cannot find where does it states the constraint that the containing box or closest ancestor needs to be positioned (i.e. has to have a computed positioned property of either `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`). How is it deduced or implied?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong document. The CSS Snapshot is just a WG Note that tells you which CSS specifications and modules are current as of a given date. It's not itself a specification. [MDN itself contains the links you should be looking at.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Specifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the spec (you were looking at the wrong document):

> [**9.8.4 Absolute
>   positioning**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#comp-abspos)
>
> The containing block for a positioned box is established by the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (or, if none exists, the initial
>   containing block).

This is relevant, as well:

> [**9.3.2 Box offsets: `top`, `right`, `bottom`,
>   `left`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#position-props)
>
> An element is said to be positioned if its `position` property has a
>   value other than `static`.

Answer (score 0):

From the official CSS specification as of 2015 is:

> This document collects together into one definition all the specs that together form the current state of Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) as of 2015. The primary audience is CSS implementers, not CSS authors, as this definition includes modules by specification stability, not Web browser adoption rate.

Inside the above link you can find a link to the [CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), where inside you can find this:

> **9.6 Absolute positioning**
>
> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). An absolutely positioned box establishes a new containing block for normal flow children and absolutely (but not fixed) positioned descendants. However, the contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow around any other boxes. They may obscure the contents of another box (or be obscured themselves), depending on the stack levels of the overlapping boxes.